# Determining the kernel of a Vandermonde-like matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

The kernel of a Vandermonde matrix can be determined using [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49255/how-to-determine-the-kernel-of-a-vandermonde-matrix) formula.

The following type of matrix has a similar structure, and should also have a one-dimensional kernel.

$$V= 
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 1 & \ldots & 1 \\
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & \ldots & x_n \\
x_1^2 & x_2^2 & x_3^2 & \ldots & x_n^2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
x_1^{m-1} & x_2^{m-1} & x_3^{m-1} & \ldots & x_n^{m-1}\\
y_1 & y_2 & y_3 & \ldots & y_n \\
y_1x_1 & y_2x_2 & y_3x_3 & \ldots & y_nx_n \\
y_1x_1^2 & y_2x_2^2 & y_3x_3^2 & \ldots & y_nx_n^2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
y_1x_1^{m-1} & y_2x_2^{m-1} & y_3x_3^{m-1} & \ldots & y_nx_n^{m-1}\\
y_1^2x_1 & y_2^2x_2 & y_3^2x_3 & \ldots & y_n^2x_n\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
y_1^{m-1}x_1^{m-1} & y_2^{m-1}x_2^{m-1} & y_3^{m-1}x_3^{m-1} & \ldots & y_n^{m-1}x_n^{m-1}\\
\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{(n-1)\times n}$$

where $n = m^2+1$ and $(x_i, y_i) \neq (x_j, y_j)$ for $i \neq j$; i.e. there are $m$ groups of $m$ rows with all possible combinations of powers $y^ax^b$ and one more column than rows.

> Does a similar analytical form exist for it? Or, would additional constraints be required, like $x_i^ay_i^b \neq x_i^cy_i^d$ for $i \neq j$?

([Crossposted to MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132242/determining-the-kernel-of-a-vandermonde-like-matrix))

Comment: Shouldn't $n=2m+1$ rather than $n=m^2+1$?

Comment: There are $m$ groups of $m$ rows (All possible combinations of powers $x^iy^j$); the matrix should have one more column than rows to give a 1-dimensional kernel, therefore $n=m^2+1$.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Nevermind.

Comment: Edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Questions: have you tried using Lagrange interpolation, as in the regular proof of the kernel of the van der monde matrix? Also, have you tried getting people on mathematica.stackexchange to experiment with different $m$?

Comment: Assuming you're in the complex field, what you're asking for is exactly which are the two-variable polynomials in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ with degree $m-1$ in both $x$ and $y$, such that they are zero on a given set of points $\{ (x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2) , ... (x_n, y_n)\}$. This is just Lagrange interpolation.

Comment: Wouldn't there be an additional row of $y_1^2 \cdots y_n^2$ before the row $y_1^2x_1 \cdots y_n^2x_n$?